Question about Visual Basic Serial COM Port project
I am new and start to learn about Visual Basic serial. I am currently using Visual Studio 2019 Community and install Visual Basic. I watch a tutorial about the project that seems similar to the one I am looking for.
But I am faced with an issue. So the code gets inputs and result should be like this. I first select the serial port, then select the value b4 pressing init button. Then afterwards I input a string to the input field and once press write then it should be displayed in the output text box. But issue is it does not display correctly.
I am unsure of the issue is with the serial port I enter or is with the code version as the tutorial is from around 11 years ago.
The serial port i am using is an iTegno sim card reader connecting to my device usb port as a serial port. I am unsure of the issue so I list out the connected device and see if there is an issue
Error output: Error
I am learning tutorial from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ChVVBNB10&list=PL2dW7m-PmsdMWq4Jb0xC3QVNHjZjOPWXi&index=4
Code:
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

    Dim myPort As Array
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallBack(ByVal [text] As String) '

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        portComboBox.Items.AddRange(myPort)
        writeButton.Enabled = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub initButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles initButton.Click
        SerialPort1.PortName = portComboBox.Text
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = baudComboBox.Text
        SerialPort1.Open()

        initButton.Enabled = False
        writeButton.Enabled = True
        closeButton.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub writeButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles writeButton.Click
        SerialPort1.Write(inputTextBox.Text & vbCr)

    End Sub

    Private Sub closeButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles closeButton.Click
        SerialPort1.Close()
        initButton.Enabled = True
        writeButton.Enabled = False
        closeButton.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
        If Me.outputTextBox.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallBack(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.outputTextBox.Text &= [text]
        End If
    End Sub

End Class


Solved, Instead of
Private Sub writeButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles writeButton.Click
        SerialPort1.Write(inputTextBox.Text & vbCr)

    End Sub

use this
Private Sub writeButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles writeButton.Click
        ' Add a newline character to the end of the input string before writing it to the textbox
        outputTextBox.Text &= inputTextBox.Text & vbCrLf
    End Sub

